# Cannot read property 'split', Discord account generator bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, undefined

Cannot read property 'split', I don't know what to do to fix this.

```
(node:21492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bradl\Desktop\account-generator-2\index.js:155:27)
    at Client.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\bradl\Desktop\account-generator-2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\bradl\Desktop\account-generator-2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\bradl\Desktop\account-generator-2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\bradl\Desktop\account-generator-2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\bradl\Desktop\account-generator-2\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\bradl\Desktop\account-generator-2\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:376:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:21492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21492) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Add command where I am getting the error part at

```
if(command === "add") { 
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("Sorry, you can't do it, you are not an admin!");  
        let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");  
        let args = messageArray.slice(1);   
        var acc = args[1].split(":");
```

Comment: show us your index.js round about line 155. the error is there. you a calling `split` on `undefined` instead of `string`

Comment: @Sysix There you go, sorry I should have thought of that

Comment: `message.content` is optional. also you are guessing that every content has atleast one space character.

Comment: try to console `message.content` and `args[1]` to check if they are strings

Comment: Log `args` and verify there's a 2nd element

Answer (score 1):

If you are in nodejs v14 you Can make :

```js
if(command === "add") { 
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("Sorry, you can't do it, you are not an admin!");  
        let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");  
        let args = messageArray.slice(1);   
        var acc = args[1]?.split(":");
```

acc was undefined but without errors.

If you are in nodejs v12, you Can just make a simple condition like that :

```js
if(command === "add") { 
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("Sorry, you can't do it, you are not an admin!");  
        let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");  
        let args = messageArray.slice(1);
        if(!args[1]) return;
        var acc = args[1].split(":");
```